# Custom Web.config section for file path definitions

Tags: c#, sql, iis

I have an application that writes files to a directory. This directory is hard coded in my C#, for example...

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\BillingExport\\EXPORTS\\TRANSACTIONS\\TYPE07.txt"))
```

I want to store the directory in the web config, and reference it from my C#. Every attempt I've made has resulted in either invalid xml or an error, so I was hoping for some help - thanks

I tried putting it in connectionStrings

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name = "exportppath1" value = "C:\BillingExport\EXPORTS\TRANSACTIONS\"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: "Every attempt I've made" well, you should tell us what you've done. That means providing code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524594/reading-custom-configuration-sections-key-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: You tagged this as `sql` and `iis`...What's the direct connection with those tags here?

Comment: streamwriter is being used to collect data from a sql database, then write it to a file (as you can see in the code snippit), and   web.config is interpreted by IIS and having invalid xml is causing my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`connectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since it make no sense on your scenario. That section is for database connection strings.

You should use [`appSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) section

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="exportDirectory" value="C:\BillingExport\EXPORTS\TRANSACTIONS" />
</appSettings>
```

And then on your code you would do

```
string exportDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exportDirectory"]
string exportFilePath = Path.Combine(exportDirectory, "TYPE07.txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportFilePath))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. As per usual I'm downvoted for asking questions.